# Firebase auth and React Hook - returning function from hook not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks, arrow-functions

I have a custom auth hook that is mean to provide the user and loading state, as well as some user based actions (such as signing out). Here is my code:

```
type UserActions = {
  signOut(): Promise<void>;
};

const useUser = (): [
  firebase.User | undefined | null,
  UserActions,
  boolean,
  firebase.auth.Error | undefined
] => {
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const [firebaseUser, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);

  return [firebaseUser, { signOut: firebase.auth().signOut }, loading, error];
};

export default useUser;
```

When I use the `signOut()` function in another file after invoking the hook, I get an error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

However, when I simply change my hook to be like so:

```
type UserActions = {
  signOut(): Promise<void>;
};

const useUser = (): [
  firebase.User | undefined | null,
  UserActions,
  boolean,
  firebase.auth.Error | undefined
] => {
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const [firebaseUser, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);

  const signOut = () => {
    return firebase.auth().signOut();
  };
  return [firebaseUser, { signOut }, loading, error];
};

export default useUser;
```

That works perfectly. What is the difference between these two cases? Not sure if I'm missing something about how arrow functions work, or maybe something with typing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've changed the context of `this` which is needed by the [implementation of `signOut()`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/auth.js#L1052-L1089) (comments removed for conciseness):

```
fireauth.Auth.prototype.signOut = function() {
  var self = this;
  var p = this.redirectStateIsReady_.then(function() {
    if (self.authEventManager_) {
      self.authEventManager_.clearRedirectResult();
    }
    
    /* ... */
  }
  
  return this.registerPendingPromise_(p);
}
```

In your first attempt, you use:

```
{ signOut: firebase.auth().signOut }
```

which effectively creates:

```
{
  signOut() {
    var self = this;
    var p = this.redirectStateIsReady_.then(function() {
      if (self.authEventManager_) {
        self.authEventManager_.clearRedirectResult();
      }
    
      /* ... */
    }
  
    return this.registerPendingPromise_(p);
  }
}
```

In that code block, `this` (and `self`) are no longer an instance of the `FirebaseAuth` class, but are your object with a shape of `{ signOut: () => Promise<void> }`. Which throws an error when you call `signOut()` because properties like `redirectStateIsReady_` and `authEventManager_` do not exist on that object (and they will be `undefined`).

This error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

is thrown because `yourObject.redirectStateIsReady_` is `undefined`, which means that the code tries (and fails) to call `(undefined).then()`.

In your second (simplified) attempt, you use:

```
const signOut = () => firebase.auth().signOut();
```

In this case, the `signOut` method hasn't been detached from it's `FirebaseAuth` class and functions as intended. This is known as "binding" a function and before arrow functions made it easier, this was done using:

```
const obj = firebase.auth();
const signOut = obj.signOut.bind(obj);
```